# Select or move more than the displayed emails in Office 365’s Outlook?

Tags: email, office-365, office-online, outlook-on-the-web

When I click the checkbox to select all the emails, it selects all the emails in my view.

[image]

Which means that if I have 900 emails in my inbox, and tick the checkbox, it will select… 9 emails. I would therefore have to reproduce the action 100 times to select them all and perform an action on all my emails.

The behavior is the same with search results when searching strings within an email.

This behavior of the app makes it nearly impossible, or at least very difficult and tedious for me to organize my emails (because, yes, I do get over 900 emails very quickly that I need to sort).

Is it possible to select **all** the emails in the inbox or **all** the emails in a search results with one click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the checkbox to select all the emails the email content window displays a menu which includes the buttons of options for the selected emails which has a header counting the number of selected emails. You can find the selection url for all the emails just below this header which reads as "**Select everything** in your Inbox folder".

[image]

Comment: Ok, works great thanks! Do you know if I can select all the emails that are the results of a search? (I might ask another question for that but it's very similar)

Comment: When I do this it does not give me an option to Move, just mark as read or mark as unread

Comment: Unfortunately, with enough messages you lose both the Move and Flag options.  Drag and drop disappears as well so I can't drag my 5,000 messages into a folder like I want.

Comment: After unchecking the Show in groups option in the sort options drop-down list of the mail box in the Outlook desktop application, I could select messages from the particular date and older.  (But then the Move... command would abort after few seconds).

Comment: That option is missing when I follow these instructions... maybe it has been removed now? How frustrating!

Comment: No such option when using search, more than 4 years later :-( 
Had to resort to holding shift + down-arrow to select up to 250 messages to move them.  Chrome starts stalling after selecting about 100 messages.  Kind of expected from M$ though, sadly enough.

Answer (score 2):

This won't help much, but if you reduce the size of the font, it'll display a few more, so a few more will get selected.

Comment: _reduce the size_ of what?

Comment: zoom-out a little your browser , is what he meant.

Comment: Ugh what a terrible interface.

Comment: The "Select Everything" option suggested by @Montag451 doesn't allow me to move all emails to a different folder. I ended up zooming out and making the font tiny, hitting (cmd + A) to select all, and dragging them into the tiny folder. Had to repeat this about 20-30x to move about 1000 emails.